# mapbox method "– setConstraintsSouthWest:northEast:" set constraints on zooming nd dragging in Ios

Tags: ios, mapbox

hi i've been using mapbox api to build custom maps 
now the problem is that i have to constrain some part of map

i done it though

– setConstraintsSouthWest:northEast:

but now it did not allow me to panning zooming nd dragging

can any body plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting constraints that are equal to or smaller than the map viewport? If the constraints are outside the map view, it should still both zoom and drag.